# why the new version of allennlp's datasetloader doesn't have the __add__ method?

Tags: allennlp

is it canceled? then how can I add two dataset for build a vocab?
in allennlp1.0, I can do

```
reader = StanfordSentimentTreeBankDatasetReader()
train_dataset = reader.read('train.txt')
dev_dataset = reader.read('dev.txt')

for inst in train_dataset + dev_dataset:
    print(inst)
    break
```

and then build a vocab together, but why allennlp 2.0 canceled it?
sorry for being a fresh in allennlp

Answer (score 1):

`DatasetReader.read()` now just returns an iterator. So you could accomplish the same thing like this:

```py
from itertools import chain

for inst in chain(train_dataset, dev_dataset):
    print(inst)
```

Comment: It’s strange why such a good method was cancelledthanks much